# how do you inherit Queue in Python

Tags: python, queue, python-2.7

when I inherit Queue i get an error:

```
super(domainQueue,self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

and when I read up on it, something about classic classes etc.

How do I initialize the base Queue class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queue.Queue` is an old-style class, and as such it doesn't support many of the features of new-style classes (such as `super`). You have two choices, to call `Queue.Queue` explicitly as suggested in TorelTwiddler's answer, or to add `object` to the bases:

```
class myQueue(Queue.Queue, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myQueue, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply get it to work, use `Queue.__init__(self)` instead.

```
class myQueue(Queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self)
```

Why does it return a `classobj` instead of a `type`? No idea.

Comment: when I use the __init__ function it fails as not having an init function